# Achieving an SQL Join

Tags: sql, join

I have three tables: `Book` which holds `id`, `title` etc..
`member` which holds `id`, `name` etc...
and `loan` which holds `member_id`, `book_id`, `returnDate` etc..

I am trying to write a query which gets me back all member details if they have loaned 3 or under three books. So far i have:

```
SELECT * FROM member m 
JOIN member_loans_book mlb ON m.id = mlb.Member_id 
  HAVING count(mlb.Book_id) <= 3
```

and it compiles but returns nothing, am i far wrong?
any pointers appreciated.

Comment: add a GROUP BY m.id clause, and consider WHERE rather than HAVING

Comment: Try using a `LEFT JOIN` as there may be people who have not even loaned a single book.

Comment: Just remarking on user.. last comment i have populated it myself so i know it should return something (if my statement was correct, which i doubt) but i understand you mean in the event of none being there so cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5f131/1)

```
SELECT m.MemberId, m.Name, COUNT(*)
FROM Member m
JOIN Loan l ON m.MemberId = l.MemberId
GROUP BY m.MemberId, m.Name
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 3
```

Comment: Thats it exactly, Thanks very much